# How do I adjust the regulatory domain on an Atheros WiFi Adapter on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a notebook (MacBook Pro) with an Atheros WiFi Adapter (Atheros AR5008X) running Windows 7 and I want to connect to a WiFi network which uses channel 12, 13 or 14 -- while my adapter is set to a restrictive regulatory domain (e.g. United States).

How do I change the regulatory domain (e.g. to France, Japan) in order to be able to connect to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way so far to adjust the regulatory domain of an Atheros device was to use CommView Atheros driver which is part of the CommView WiFi Sniffer. The drivers might not be available separately from CommView, but once you install a trial version, you don't actually have to use it:
http://www.tamos.com/download/main/index.php

Afterwards, use their utility to change the regulatory domain:
http://www.tamos.com/files/rcu.zip (reference from http://www.tamos.com/htmlhelp/commwifi/faq.htm).

BTW, I've found references on the Internet to registry keys adding a "ccode" parameter to the driver key. However, while this adds the property to the device's Parameters property page, it has no effect.